problem in reinstall postgresql on ubuntu
I had installed postgresql 16. I deleted postqresql using the following commands:
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql postgresql-*
dpkg -l | grep postgres
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql postgresql-doc postgresql-common

Now I need to install it again, but I get the following error:

Failed to fetch https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgresql-16/libpq5_16.3-1.pgdg22.04%2b1_amd64.deb Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

A picture of the full text of the error
Ubuntu version 22.04
